# android: Notify a fragment when something happened in another fragment

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, fragment, android-jetpack-compose

I Built a fragment (using jetpack compose to built the views) and in this fragment I have a button. every time this button was clicked, I want to notify another fragment to do something.
How can I do that?
I use MVVM and MVI design patterns.
Thanks.

Comment: You can use an activity-scoped viewmodel shared by both fragments and a Channel or SharedFlow to transmit events among the fragments. 

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

You can send value to another fragment  , but this fragment should runing in navigation componnent

set this code in onCreate another fragment

// RESPONSE is statict value key
// RESPONSE_VALUE is statict value key

```
 setFragmentResultListener(MainFramgent.RESPONSE) { key, bundle ->
        val answer = bundle.getInt(MainFramgent.RESPONSE_VALUE)
       
    }
```

in main fragment when click on button set this code

```
  findNavController().navigateUp()
  setFragmentResult(
        RESPONSE,
        bundleOf(RESPONSE_VALUE to answer)
    )
```